# Overwrite prefixes on image files/folder

Tags: python, pandas, windows

Is there a way to overwrite image file names that is saved on desktop. There are prefixes that i want to adjust.

Ex. 
Before  s_pclr-01.jpg         -> What i want (AFter)     01.jpg

Please see the code following. I created a path to pull folder with 100s of image name that has s_pclr, pclr-, and s_pclr. just want to be able to overwrite them.

```
colors_path = os.listdir(path)
for n in colors_path: 
    d = n.replace('s_pclr-', '') #strong text
    f = n.replace('pclr-', '')
    e = n.replace('s_pclr_', '')
    print('{}, {}, {}'.format(d, f, e))
    os.rename(path, d)
```

I get this error after running it:

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\Users\david.han\OneDrive - Barco Uniforms\Desktop\Colors'

Comment: Have you checked if the  full-path you passed to the `listdir` method contains a "Colors" directory?

Comment: yes, it gives me this. as an example
s_pclr_ORT.jpg
s_pclr_SAH.jpg
s_pclr_SPO.jpg
s_pclr_WIN.jpg
s_pclr_WIR.jpg
TAQ.jpg
TAT.jpg
TBB.jpg
TBE.jpg
TBL.jpg
TBM.jpg
TCE.jpg

Comment: another issue may be because of permissions. For the example directory list you posted, did you use the Window Manager tool on Windows or some other python tool?

Comment: @NanaOwusu I used jupyter notebook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot rename the `path`, try this instead that renames the actual files:

```
colors_path = os.listdir(path)
for n in colors_path: 
    d = n.replace('s_pclr-', '') #strong text
    f = n.replace('pclr-', '')
    e = n.replace('s_pclr_', '')
    print('{}, {}, {}'.format(d, f, e))
    # assuming "n" to be the old name and "d" to be the new one
    os.rename( os.path.join( path, n), os.path.join( path, d))
```

Comment: really appreciate this. didn't know i had to use os.path.join to make the actual change. thank you